# Why fstream methods returns references to "*this"?

Tags: c++, std, fstream

I've recently started coding in C++, but I have long time writing in C. So i'm reading the methods from fstream class and I've figured out that every method which could be a procedure (returning nothing) is returning a reference to the object that called its method. (fstream& fstream::read(char_type* __s, streamsize __n) for example).

Why is done this way?

I'm coding a little layer on top of fstream class so I'm wondering if I should return a reference in my read methods too.

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: One thing it does allow for is chaining of invocations,including overloaded redirection operators. I'd recommend following suit as it presents your users with some flexibile options for usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Returning a reference to the stream object itself gives you an excellent way to *check* the validity of I/O operations: If an operation fails, the stream object is in a fail state, which means that it will evaluate to `false` in a boolean context. Thus we can write:

```
while (std::getline(instream, str)) { /* ... process line ... */ }

if (anotherstream >> x >> y) { /* process x and y */ }
else { /* error, at least one extraction failed */ }

if (!laststream.read(buf, sizeof(buf)) { /* error */ }
```

Note in particular the repeated call in the second example: Each extraction returns a reference to the stream object, and so we can concatenate multiple extractions in one statement, and if *any* of them fail, the entire operation will evaluate `false`.

Here's a practical example, parsing lines of the form `[x y z]` from the standard input:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    char l, r;
    double x, y, z;

    if (!(iss >> l >> x >> y >> z >> r) || (l != '[') || (r != ']'))
    {
        std::cerr << "Malformed line ('" << line << "'), skipping.\n";
        continue;
    }

    std::cout << "You said: " << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#method-chaining

It's basically why:

```
cout << "Hello " << "World";
```

works.

(Though, as Luchian Grigore pointed out, cout is not an fstream.  The same idea applies though, and his answer offers an example of an fstream.)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Ah, very good point.  I was thinking streams in general.  Same idea still applies though with chaining.  Just not as direct.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Really the example could have been anything that used chaining.  Even *A a; a.method1().method2();*  The rest of his question is implicitly answered through him understand what the purpose of a fluent interface is.  Either way though, thanks for not downvoting :).

Answer (score 4):

That's so you can use **[method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)**.

```
stream << "foo";
stream << "bar";
```

can be replaced with

```
stream << "foo" << "var";
```